# PostgreSQL data type text vs varchar without length

Tags: postgresql, datatypes

In PostgreSQL you can create a column with data type **character varying** (without length precision) or **text** like this:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN c1 varchar;
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN c2 text;
```

Is there a difference between these two data types?

The documentation is not clear about it. They say :

> If **character varying** is used without length specifier, the type
>   accepts strings of any size.
>
> [...]
>
> In addition, PostgreSQL provides
>   the **text** type, which stores strings of any length.

It seems that these two datatypes are equivalent but it is not explicit... More info about this?

Thank you,
Nico

Comment: See the answer at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/questions/240813/whats-difference-between-varchar-and-text-type-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no difference between the two data types.  They use the exact same storage and the same operators.